# laravel, send customer id with stripe information

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to send customer id along with stripe information to the stripe dashboard? I don't know how to do this or this is required if I want to save the payment methods for every customer in my database
I found in stripe dashboard that the customer is none, please see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VZhN.jpg
here stripe jquery:

```
if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    stripe.createToken(number).then({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
  }, stripeResponseHandler);
}
```

Stripe controller

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

Stripe\Charge::create ([
    "amount"   => $total*100,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source"   => "tok_visa"
]);
```

Comment: Hi Farag, you need to save stripe-user-id in the `users` table.

Comment: how can I do this???

Comment: When you register user on stripe then it provides a user-id. Save this id in your `users` table and perform all transactions corresponding to that user-id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can can send addition paramaters as array using metadata keyword
>   in stripe,
>   Like the below code

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    Stripe\Charge::create ([
            "amount" => $total*100,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "source" => "tok_visa",
            "metadata" => array("cus_id" => $cus_id, "name" => $user_name)

    ]);
```